# jQuery plugin is undefined although is properly included before my js code

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, jquery-plugins

I am working on this quite strange issue for several days now, and I really don't understand why that happens.

Basically, the environment is WordPress and I am including two js files:

> vendor.js -> generated by gulp and all it does is concatenating bower
>   libs together
>
> myScript.js -> my code

What I know (with proof):

- The vendor file is included before my code (checked from the console)
- The plugin I am using is included in vendor.js (opened the file in a new tab in chrome)
- Both files are loaded correctly (i printed some debug console log and they are in the console)

BUT even if everything looks fine to me, the plugin is still undefined for whatever reason.
The plugin I am using is this one: https://github.com/idiot/unslider

and the error i'm getting in the console is this:

> Uncaught ReferenceError: unslider is not defined

This is the part of my code where I call and need this plugin:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  console.log("unslider is ", unslider);
  $('#topBannerSlider').unslider({
    autoplay: true,
    delay: 10000,
    keys: true,
    nav: true,
    arrows: {
      prev: '<a class="unslider-arrow prev fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></a>',
      next: '<a class="unslider-arrow next fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></a>'
    }
  });

  $('#homePageTestimonialsCarousel').unslider({
    autoplay: true,
    delay: 20000,
    keys: true,
    nav: true,
    arrows: false
  });
}
```

and it does the same if I try to load it before `jQuery(document).ready()` event, like so:

```
console.log("unslider is ", unslider);
jQuery(document).ready(function($) {
  $('#topBannerSlider').unslider({
    autoplay: true,
    delay: 10000,
    keys: true,
    nav: true,
    arrows: {
      prev: '<a class="unslider-arrow prev fa fa-arrow-circle-left"></a>',
      next: '<a class="unslider-arrow next fa fa-arrow-circle-right"></a>'
    }
  });

  $('#homePageTestimonialsCarousel').unslider({
    autoplay: true,
    delay: 20000,
    keys: true,
    nav: true,
    arrows: false
  });
}
```

Do you have any suggestion? what else can I try? what else can it be? I am really stuck and any help would be really appreciated. Thanks a lot

Comment: check the order those scripts are being loaded, first include jQuery, then unslider, then your js code.

Comment: Hi, I checked it, everything is in the proper order..that's why it's really strange to me

Comment: in the code samples they load unslider.js after html is defined, are you doing the same?

Comment: Do you have the `async` or `defer` attribute set on the `<script>` tag which is loading the library? Please also check the console for errors, as there should be some clue as to why your code isn't working

Comment: I have copied your code and it's working fine. The only thing was you had a `)` missing at the end of your code. Not sure if this is unrelated issue

Comment: @derloopkat hi, the missing bracket shouldn't be an issue as I write with coffeescript and that gets compiled with a gulp task. Regarding HTML I am actually loading it in the header and not the footer, I will try to include it in the footer and let you know, thanks for now

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan Hi, no I haven't added any async nor defer attribute to the scripts. There are no other issues in the console apart from that

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I get this right you say WordPress, so try

`jQuery` insted of `$`

I have this problem before and this fix it.

WordPress, PHP, JQuery and $ don't mix ;).

Comment: I don't believe it, but this actually solved the issue! Really strange, but hey, thanks man you saved my weekend :)

Comment: anytime dude ;)